# Finding the maximum of a range

Tags: java, android-studio

I have got the range of ISO that the camera suoports, however I do not know how to find the the maximum and minimum of this

`Range<Integer> ISO = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE);`

Comment: You'd need to read the javadoc of the Range class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Range` object has a `getMaximum()` method that should achieve what you're looking for. More information on this can be found in the [Range documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html#getMaximum--).

In order to retrieve the maximum ISO (`Integer`) from your `Range` object, you'll need to call the `Range.getMaximum()` method as per the documentation linked above. So in your case, `ISO.getMaximum()` will return the maximum ISO `Integer` in your `Range`.

I hope that helps!